# Windows 10 Memory Leak - Cannot find source

Tags: windows-10, memory-leaks

I apparently have a massive memory like on my upgraded Windows 10 system. I have seen "System" (PID 4) slowly use more and more RAM. My "NT Kernal & System" has already used more than 5GB of RAM. Attached I have my poolmon data, however I do not know how to interpret it.

[image]

Comment: [See if RAMMap helps spot the offending program](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229)

Comment: @Moab Thank you for your reply. I tried running RAMMap however it does not appear to run on Windows 10. Thank you anyway.

Comment: try task manager, look for an entry that memory usage climbs.

Comment: @Moab The entry is "System"/"NT Kernal & System"

Comment: I would clean install Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It usually asociated with drivers.
Try typing this in Command Prompt(run as administrator),

> cd drivers

then

```
findstr /s [tag name] *.*
```

Then wait for a few sec. it will show the name of the *.sys file(s). find it in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers . Check its properties. You'll get info about what driver associated with this file. Update that driver

Hope it helps, cos I got the same problem. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried this and just tried it again except every time I do findstr in the drivers folder, it runs forever and does not stop.

Comment: Don't worry about it. There is nothing in the poolmon output that indicates excessive pool usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen "System" (PID 4) slowly use more and more RAM. My "NT Kernal & System" has already used more than 5GB of RAM.

[This is a new feature of Windows 10 called Memory Compression. Instead of paging data out of the RAM to the pagefile, Windows compresses them and store it inside the system process.](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557)

You have a lot of other software that uses a lot of RAM.