# Why is my System is using a lot of memory

Tags: windows, memory

Can anyone tell me why my system is using roughly 2000 or more memory when I have no big applications open, the only things open on my computer is Skype and google chrome. Also it says its at 96% but i have 8000MB and all together it doesn't look like it can be higher then 3000. I have already tried restarting my Computer and scanning for malware

Windows 10 64 bit OS

[image]

Comment: If the memory isn't higher than 3GB even though you have more installed, you need to install 64bit version of Windows.

Comment: What does the memory look like on the performance tab or Resource Monitor?

Comment: I wrote here a bit of the SYSTEM memory usage in Windows 10: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557

Answer (score -2):

Modern operating systems try to waste as little memory as possible. This behavior is by design.

If the OS is detecting less than 4GB even though you have a 64-bit OS, your BIOS probably has memory remapping turned off. You should turn it on.

Comment: This is both incorrect and irrelevant. Memory used for background caching does not show up in the way the screenshot shows.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq It does on Windows 10 due to memory compression. So it's not incorrect. Why do you think it's irrelevant?

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoters would explain the reasons for their downvotes. This is the correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question asked and provides no information, reference, or explanation of "memory compression". Nor did the OP say or ask anything about memory remapping or how much memory the OS is detecting.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq The OP asked, "Can anyone tell me why my system is using roughly 2000 or more memory when I have no big applications open". The answer is that this is by design. There's no reason to think an explanation of memory compression would be helpful here. As for memory remapping not being a possible problem, the OP says, "i have 8000MB and all together it doesn't look like it can be higher then 3000" which can be caused by memory remapping being off. I'm trying to help him solve his actual problem, if he has one. (Which he may not.)

Comment: "This is by design" is not an answer to *why* any more than the answer to "Why does the heart beat" or "Why does the message XYZ come up" is "This is by design".

Comment: @qasdfdsaq While the actual word used is "why", the OP is asking why because he thinks something is wrong. "Nothing is wrong" *is* the right answer. Only a very poor consultant gives his customer what the customer thinks he wants, a good consultant gives the customer what his expertise tells him the customer needs. You were wrong, you claimed my answer was "incorrect", forcing a detour into discussions of complex design details that are irrelevant to the OP. You are trying to turn his question into something it isn't. If you want to understand the details, ask your own question.

Comment: No, I was not wrong, you remain wrong but deny it. If you're going to whine about downvotes and then whine when someone explains it to you, don't bother asking in the first place, you clearly can't deal with it.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq So you stand by this comment, "Memory used for background caching does not show up in the way the screenshot shows", even though you now know that it's wrong because of the way Windows 10 memory compression works?

Comment: I don't see what's so hard to understand about "Memory used for background caching does not show up in the way the screenshot shows" Perhaps you don't understand the difference between caching and paging, or you don't know what memory compression actually is.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Umm, yes, memory used for background caching does show up in the way the screenshot shows. And I do understand the difference between caching and paging -- paging is a form of caching, essentially using main memory as a cache. And I know what memory compression is, precious main memory is conserved by compressing memory that is infrequently accessed. This is a form of background caching and it does show up in the way the screenshot shows.

Comment: Ermm, no, because it doesn't. Memory used for caching doesn't appear on that page at all. Memory used for caching is *never* compressed, compressed pages are *never* cached. One is not a form of the other, they are completely different and **mutually exclusive**

Comment: @qasdfdsaq You are, again, wrong. Caching is, by definition, using a small fast storage space to hold a subset of information backed by a larger slower storage space. The compressed pages we're talking about here are stored in RAM and spilled to disk. But more importantly, they're part of the process of using RAM itself as a cache.

Comment: You are, once again, both wrong, and completely clueless and have no idea what you're on about. Nomatter what way you try to wrangle it, your answer is still both incorrect and irrelevant. Memory used for background caching does not show up in the way the screenshot shows. That is why your answer was downvoted. Arguing all you want will not change that. Since you also failed to read it the first time, I repeat: "If you're going to whine about downvotes and then whine when someone explains it to you, don't bother asking in the first place, you clearly can't deal with it. "