# How to diagnose low memory on Windows 10?

Tags: memory, windows-10, virtual-memory

2 weeks ago I upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on my system; Core i5, 4GB RAM. It was working fine, Now I am getting “Windows on low memory." messages.

System process is taking too much memory. If I am not wrong it’s an issue of Windows 10.

Can any one suggest how to resolve this issue? Or any official upgrade by Microsoft for this issue? [image] 
Whenever I restart my laptop system process is normal but after few minute System process exceed up-to 700mb. I just don't understand, as it was working fine two weeks ago. And I don't use heavy software except chrome, photoshop and media player.

Comment: add a screen shot of your task manager .. And sometimes it happens because of virus attack , http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/preventing-low-memory-problems#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Added screenshot, please have a look

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram)

Comment: I wrote a bit of the high SYSTEM usage in Windows 10 here: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557. Chrome is ressource hog, use a better browser like Firefox ;)

Comment: +16GB can be as cheap as $75 so it may be worth the investment to check out

Answer (score 3):

The system process taking lots of memory is not an issue on Windows 10. It's a result of a change in the way Windows manages memory that's in use but hasn't been accessed in some time. The data in it is compressed and the physical memory containing the compressed data is managed by the system process. This doesn't indicate any problem.

When you get messages indicating Windows is low on memory, it's referring to virtual memory, not physical memory. This could be caused by excessive consumption of physical memory or a driver leak, but it's much more commonly caused by having no page file or too small a page file.