# High Memory usage in Windows 10

Tags: memory, performance, windows-10, troubleshooting, memory-leaks

I cannot figure out whats been just eating up my RAM lately. I tried looking with poolmon. It shows that the highest usage is Proc. So after searching for a possible driver issue. findstr /s Proc *.* I get many returns such as WUDFPf.sys , xboxgip.sys, ws2ifsl.sys, WpUpFltr.sys, 1394ohci.sys  etc..

I'm not sure what is the problem after having all of those return.

[image: taskmanager SS]

[image: poolmon SS]

Comment: look if SYSTEM process "uses" too much RAM: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557. In this case it is fine. The 1GB of nonpaged are a bit to high. To see what Proc tag is used you have to use xperf/WPA to trace it: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool (use the Win10 SDK/WPT: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Windows 10 by design uses a new memory management system that compresses data, for this reason reported memory usage will be slightly higher, for the same system configuration as before.  Your screenshots don't indicate anything out of the ordinary honestly.  Unused memory is useless to a system, if required Windows will immediately, assigned the memory it is using to your tasks until said tasks are running it will use it for other things to make your system more stable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram)

Comment: I'm looking into SYSTEM process right now. Usually everyday I'll get a Windows prompt telling me to close something due to loss of memory. So I'm inclined to believe its not due to Windows 10 memory management.

Comment: Ramhound is correct - these screens do not indicate any sort of problem. Those "prompts" are not due to shortage of RAM (Windows actually has no error message for "shortage of RAM") but shortage of commit limit. At the moment your system is not exhibiting this issue (commit limit is 18.4 GB, commit charge only 6.8) but that is what causes that pop-up to occur. I notice you only have a 2.4 GB pagefile - I would increase it. The next time it happens, please do not "ok" through the error message. Grab and post a capture of Task manager's Details display sorted by the "commit size" column.

Comment: RAMMap is now Win10 compatible. Post some pictures of RAMMap: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx