# Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM Weird Poolmon.exe :(

Tags: memory, windows-10, memory-leaks

Since I upgraded to Windows 10, my system has been consuming RAM excessively

[image]

I've been reading a bit and determined it's likely a driver leaking memory. So I got myself the Windows Driver Kit and tracked memory usage with poolmon:

[image]

However, I don't really know how to proceed from here. This poolmon.exe is very weird. Is the item tagged "APL-Paged" the culprit in this issue? How do I go from there to actually identifying the driver?

I tried some stuff like "C:\Windows\System32\drivers>findstr /s APL ." but it returned no results.

So yeah, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, this is [fine and by design](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557). Instead of paging out data to the page file and (mostly slow HDD), Windows 10 compresses the data and stores it in the SYSTEM process.

[image]

Read my link for a much deeper answer.

Comment: I have read your link and I find that this high memory usage is due to default design, but for me using 1 or 2gb of ram is freezing my PC and I think that 8 or 9 hours could damage my PC or at least reduce its life :(

Comment: what happens if you press the CAPS LOCK key during the freeze? Does the light on the keyboard toggle or not?

Comment: It switch on :)

Comment: ok, in this case it is an software issue. Run RAMMap to see which other processes use most RAM: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx , close them to reduce the compression of Windows