# Could Windows 10's compression store be causing sluggish performance?

Tags: memory, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I often use a program overnight that consumes a large amount of RAM (I think around 7GB), and then in the morning I close the program. When I had Windows 7 the memory usage would drop as soon as I shut the program. However, on Windows 10 even once the program is closed the memory usage continues.

[image: Windows 10 RAM usage]

The memory usage is mostly attributable to System. Here it's not using much CPU, although sporadically it does use quite a bit of CPU.

[image: Task manager]

A related question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram),and the most upvoted (although not the accepted) answer seems to take the line that usage of memory was a feature and not a bug. It states:

> In Windows 10, we have added a new concept in the Memory Manager
>   called a compression store, which is an in-memory collection of
>   compressed pages. This means that when Memory Manager feels memory
>   pressure, it will compress unused pages instead of writing them to
>   disk.

It seems to me that this is making my computer sluggish. What's going on, and what should I do about it?

Comment: try the TH2 Build 10586 which is likely to be the November 2015 Update for Win10 and look if this improves your situation.

Comment: Threshold 2, will likely be called `Fall Update` not ` November 2015 Update` if it isn't called Threshold 2.

Comment: The compression store runs in the "system" process, which per your display is using less than a tenth of your CPU. So, no, it's very unlikely to be "making your computer sluggish."