# How to disable Windows 10 System and Compress Memory feature?

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-registry, compression, group-policy

As the title says, how do we disable it?

It maybe promising for low memory devices but not on a 32 Gig Ram, it consumes about 50% of disk access and it slows down other access on local disks.

There were few answers discussed in [How to disable Windows 10 memory compression?](https://superuser.com/questions/1000485/how-to-disable-windows-10-memory-compression) but it does not work now on Windows 10 Build 1511

Comment: update to 1607, the 1511 is now out of support because the Business Brach is now also 1607

Comment: 1607 is a bit buggy and has frequent freezing (reset required) so I am in 1511, the solution on the link does not work either

Comment: it works in 1607 as I tested it. Submit your issues in the feedback hub and go back to 1607

Comment: I used the power shell, I get parameter `mc` not found.

Comment: because this parameter is added in v1607 and not v1511.