# How to see the details of system process resource usage?

Tags: windows, task-manager, resource-usage

In task manager the is a process called "system". it uses resources but I want to know what is it? and what causes to use this amount of memory, cpu or disk.
what should I do?
I'm using windows 10.

Comment: which Windows? in Win10, the system process hosts compressed memory: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557

Answer (score 0):

I'd start [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241677/how_to_use_resource_monitor.html) with Resource Monitor and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) with Process Explorer.  It should give you more detail you're looking for.