# System and compressed memory taking too much memory

Tags: compression

[image: Please see this image first]

I recently upgraded my windows 10 OS but having a new issue with this "System and compressed memory" its taking too much memory and i have never seen this types of process in my task manager its kind of new to me. Please help me if  you have any possible solution.

Comment: See [this article](http://lifehacker.com/why-is-windows-10s-system-process-using-so-much-ram-1725076206) for more information.

Comment: you mean if i use more RAM using another program, this thing will release those RAM automatically ?

Comment: Yes. It's nothing to worry about, it's entirely by design and isn't stealing RAM from other processes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity since I agree, its not actually problem, but how exactly did you determine that the process is using "too much" memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram). See the highest voted answer which explains "compressed memory".

Comment: You knwo @Ramhound if you run your personal computer daily you will must have an idea about what Takes too much RAM or  Process. For example, i use photoshop and illustrator and chrome together so, i know how much RAM the take to run properly. But after this new process starts , something was not right. I can feel it :)

Comment: You did recently upgrade though so that's a change that occurred. Are you sure you've had enough time to benchmark to get a feel what's normal and not normal since this change? Meaning what's normal before the Windows 10 upgrade may not be since the Windows 10 upgrade since you "feel" something is not right.

Comment: ow ! you mean if i upgrade my OS ,i need more RAM or More Processor ?
my friend ! i have used win 7, 8.1, 10 but both never had this issue at least RAM issue. so upgrading new version causes this problem ? ridiculous !

Comment: Another strategy would be to kill all the chrome instances, skype, etc. when running critical processes for your need such as Photoshop, etc. when needed too. If you add all the Chrome.exe up, that's more than the process you're worried about so just kill some of those HOGS when you need to run critical processes when RAM is an issue.  Quick thought. Otherwise, buy more memory or higher density RAM chips as it 's not too expensize now days. You know what you need and don't need better than anyone else so that is an option if absolutely needed otherwise.

Comment: @Samir - You nearly have single Chrome tabs using more memory then that process is using.  `Windows 10 Version 1511` contains a more refined memory management system, which means in general more memory will be consumed but more application data will also be contained in that space because of the compression.  *If a single 155 MB process is causing you that much trouble there is something else going on.*

Comment: here is a latest screenshot , http://i.imgur.com/ptldxb9.png
you can see that photoshop is taking very low memory rather that program is acting like a RAM destroyer

Comment: Samir - read the links. Your issue is not the 'System and compressed' process; your issue is your comprehension of how that is trying to help you against your excessive  Chrome tab usage. Quit Chrome, all will be well.