# Im seeing high battery usage by the system under Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, memory, battery

Recently my lap started to heat up. When on battery it's draining very fast. When I checked the task manager... the `System and Compressed memory` shows nearly 1.5G to 750 MB of memory usage. Never saw this much earlier. Now for several days it's like this. When i checked the batter use, it says `76%` used for System! What might be the issue?

Comment: You are running memory intensive programs.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I find what's the exact program that's using high ram?

Comment: Task Manager or any number of programs that report additional information on your system's memory usage.

Comment: @Ramhound According to task manager the biggest ram user is clearly `System and Compressed memory`

Comment: The usage you are seeing is actually normal.  Windows 10 Version 1511 will use slightly more memory, due the memory manger using compression to store additional data, you unlikely have an actual memory usage problem. Unused memory serves no purpose, any memory that is needed, will be given to a process that requires it.

Comment: the memory usage is by design in Win10: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557 The battery drain comes from the ugly apps that run all the time