# Windows 10 Task Manager System Processes

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, resource-usage

Resource consumption in Windows 10's task manager doesn't add up. System consumes 50% of RAM (out of 8GB) and over 90% of disk usage (out of about ~80MB/s) regularly, however the processes are not listed under my user. How do I track down what's causing this consumption and get my resources back?

Edit:
used the processhacker application to empty working set RAM, which dropped RAM consumption from 4.7 to 2.5 with my resource consumption at .8 before and after. It has stayed at this point since then. I still don't understand what that result means and I still don't understand why my IO demand is high when R/W low. Sometimes it will cap at 2 MB/s and sometimes it will cap at 50

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram)

Answer (score 0):

You see a new [Windows 10 feature](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557), where Windows compresses data that would be paged out into the disk (agefile) in earlier Windows versions, but now tries to keep them in RAM to make Windows faster.