# Avoiding memory corruption while gaming

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

So I've gotten myself a lot of BSOD's while gaming in the past, and I'd often google up the errors that came up on my screen and *hopefully* resolve the issue by a driver update of some sort.

Just recently I was able to "sense" a BSOD that was going to happen because my "System and Compressed Memory" process on my Task manager was going bonkers, even causing my sound system to make weird sound raps and eventually stop. I quickly decided to end the game that I was playing immediately, and let it calm down. And just to be safe, I did a restart after it calmed down (to avoid anything among the lines of my ram being stuck 'cus that thing was still bonkers) and everything went fine.

Are there any "rules" that I should adhere or lookout for when I'm gaming to prevent BSODs' from happening? These bastards come really randomly and it would help if anyone of you could share your experiences and practices. (Aside tuning down graphics of game and those normal things that you see everywhere)

[My minidump files for March if anyone is interested](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7C01InhPrmOdVpRTTd5WjZ2QkU&usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you verified that your memory manufacturer and currently used timing are compatible with your motherboard?  If those are off, it can lead to bsod's

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using a pre-packed laptop that I buy off the shelves of an electronics store. Well these BSODs don't come very often which is a relief. They come very randomly (1, or at worst 3 times a month).

Comment: the memory usage of SYSTEM is by design, it is a feature to keep data in RAM. In older Windows version, the data were written to the pagefile http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557 to get help about the BSOD, share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: @Kei Ah nevermind if it is a laptop then. I didn't know it was a prepackaged computer. Does it only BSOD in that one game or others? If just in that game then prob bugs in the game. You could possibly adjust the Open GL / DirectX level that is used in the game?

Comment: Many things can cause BSODs. You really need to provide the minidumps or at least provide the error codes as (hopefully) visible in Event Viewer.

Comment: @EricF It can be any game. Usually games that have a lot of particles (Those ridiculous effects in MMORPGs) and higher end FPS games (nothing like battle field and those, my laptop is not that beefy)

Comment: @DanielB I googled those errors before, and I have my own mini dump viewer as well and I solved those errors usually by updating my drivers after showing someone my mini dump.

Comment: @DanielB I added my minidump files if you're interested.

Comment: One bluescreen occurred when the resolution changed, one was caused by a Juniper Networks driver, one by AMD graphics drivers and unknown. I suggest you remove MalwareBytes Antimalware, whatever Juniper thingy you’re using, Intel HAXM (Android Emulation related) and the XIGNCODE3 anti-cheat software (if possible). Also, update all drivers, preferably directly from the manufacturer (not Lenovo).

Comment: Daniel also checked the dmp and yes some drivers caused crashes. update them and the memory usage is a good feature.

Answer (score 0):

The issues come from bugs in the game or the driver code, and there is not much you can do.

Except not to play badly coded games or not use hardware with badly coded drivers that produce a lot of them - but that's hardly a solution.