# How to display memory consumed by drivers in Windows 10? It looks like I have a memory leak

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers

I'm experiencing symptoms similar to [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1106158/windows-10-low-virtual-memory-probably-memory-leak-when-computer-is-left-idle) on my [GPD Win](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPD_Win). Here are my memory stats after a day of use with no applications running, showing that about 2 GiB of memory are gone:

[image]

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1106539/427799) suggests that the video driver may be the culprit, therefore I would like to see how much memory is consumed by the drivers. Is there a tool or a technique which allows me to estimate the memory consumption of individual drivers, or at least estimate the total?

Edit: it looks like my issue is caused by Steam client leaking handles, similar to what's described [here](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/windows-10-memory-leak.1155273/). The tag name is not the same, but my issue doesn't appear when Steam is not started.

Comment: non paged pool is too high. use poolmon to see which tag is using too much memory and next the findstr command to see which driver belongs to the tag

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks. I've already seen your answer (and closed my question as a dupe). In my case, the offending tag is `Inte`, which is found in 30 or so `sys` files. Given that I also experience graphical glitches/crashes, I suspect this is related to Intel HD graphic drivers. Unfortunately, I've already tried upgrading to the latest drivers for Cherry Trail, and downgrading to the previous "beta" release with no improvements in memory management.

Comment: run the xperf command and analyze the ETL in WPA to see which driver use Inte tag.

Comment: if you need help, zip the ETL and share the zip so that I can look at it.