# Where did the "compressed memory" go?

Tags: windows-10, memory, compression, memory-management

In some older versions of Windows 10 there's a *"System and Compressed Memory"* process indicating that compressed pages are counted there, after many people complained that their *System* process consumes too much RAM and/or CPU.

However recently after an update I realized that the *System* process' name has been revert back, and also "consumes" much less RAM than before. Why is that?

[image: system process]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a change since the 1607 update to no [longer confuse users](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557). Now there is a pseudo process called `Memory Compression` where the compressed data are shown:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is right but I am confused your screenshot indicates 1511 but your saying it was changed with 1607 do is compression memory just pre1607 or am I reading your answers incorrectly?  Memory compression was a new feature overall to Windows 10 though so I am mega confused

Comment: @Ramhound the old picture was from a insider build of the RS1 branch which still had the older 1511 name. the taskmgr of Build 14393 doesn't seam to have the entry **Memory Compression** any longer. I posted a picture of process hacker which shows it.

Comment: Ahh; ok; that makes sense