# Windows 10 RAM usage not accounted for

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, memory, performance, memory-leaks

Whilst I've seem some similar questions, I can't troubleshoot the problem I am having as they tend to be specific to that user asking.

When I run my PC > 24 hours (I have reasons why I do this), my RAM usage creeps up. I had my PC on all weekend, and my ram was maxed out at 100%.

When I check in task manager, the usage is not accounted for at all.
I have 32GB RAM, and usually the highest usage on the RAM will be a Google Chrome process with half a gig usage, a handful of processes over 100MB total, then others with smaller amounts. Never enough to account for the actual usage.

After looking through other answers I downloaded Process Explorer, and looked at the Working Set column. There is a process there called "memory Compression", with 6,344K private byes but a working set of 2,6922,748K. Thats at time of writing, where my PC hasn't been on as long as I noramlly would let it run in total before a reboot. Total RAM usage currently sits at 50%.

Some people suggested it might be a driver with a memory leak, but I am unsure how to diagnose a problem further here. [image]
Theres an image of some of what I'm seeing. In 1-3 days, I would expect to see that at 32 GB, but with seemingly no extra processes using RAM etc.

Comment: you see the [new memory compression of Windows 10 in action](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557)

Answer (score 0):

Stop looking at your RAM usage.

If your computer has RAM available, the point is for the computer to USE said RAM.  If the RAM is unused, it means that when you need to access data, the computer will have to access the HDD and load it, which is super slow, vs reading it straight from RAM.  You'll want the computer to pre-load things based on your usage patterns.

Look up Windows and super-fetch and pre-caching and all the technologies related to it.

Now, if you have an actual problem, then list the actual problem, like, "I need to do this thing that uses lots of RAM, but computer crashes."

Your system monitor is giving you a useless piece of information (RAM usage), and you're trying to fix a "problem" that is non-existent.

Comment: AS stated in OP - My RAM usage hits 100% after a given amount of time. At which point (this part wasnt stated as such but I thought implied), it crawls to a much slower rate. Whilst unsupervised.

Comment: Also AS stated, that's how it is suppose to work.  Read up on "Super-fetch" and "pre-caching".  You WANT it to load unsupervised, because it is saving you time in the future when you need the data... RAM usage hitting 100% is **not an actual problem**!

Comment: If you look at the other "memory leak" questions, they post an **actual problem**, like being unable to run a game, or the computer responds slowly.  **You do not have an actual problem** in your question, other than "You don't like Windows using RAM."

Comment: A memory leak in itself is a problem. The computer runs slower when the RAM is all used up. Even if it didn't, having a memory leak is a problem whether it causes negative effects or not.

Comment: The point, is that without any extra processes running, the available RAM slowly decreases, without any visible processes taking any extra RAM. This then causes the PC to run a lot slower, at which point I restart, but I can't always be there in time to restart it, so stopping it using all memory when it clearly doesn't need to use it all would solve my problem.

Comment: Then state that as the problem.  "Computer runs slower over the day until I restart."  Don't start assuming it to be memory related with no diagnostic, and then **not stating the actual problem in the question**.  You need to edit your question to show the **actual problem**, and **what you did to alleviate the problem**, and the **diagnostics used** (if any).