# Windows10 "System" using all memory

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

A process called "System" on my windows10 laptop is using all the memory. I can't play any games because of this. Chrome too freezes. It's almost impossible to use any program.

I've 8GB Ram. The "system" process is using 70-80% of it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do a boot in safe mode, see what that gives back...

Comment: It's most likely a faulty driver, or worse, dying hardware.  See https://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram

Comment: The real problem here is that you are showing 13.3 GB in your paged pool. 
As a rule of thumb, paged pool should _generally_ be no more than about twice the nonpaged pool. Your first step should be to try using poolmon to identify the type of thing being stored. See this answer: superuser.com/a/949246/348119 by @magicandre1981. That answer covered nonpaged pool usage, but the techniques are the same, except that In the instructions for using poolmon you want to type the "p" key until it shows only "Pagd" instead of "NonP" or both, and then type the "B" key to sort by byte usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* processes running under *System* credentials. MS SysInternals' [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can show a bit finer granularity, but unfortunately does not display CPU use by driver. However, it *can* be set to check each executable at VirusTotal, to see if malware is the culprit (e.g. a bitcoin miner running in the background). Donb't be concerned if there are just one or two alerts out of many, as shown below, but if four or more AV engines identify malware, do a *complete* scan with an effective tool. Try another (free) one-time AV scan, in addition to whatever tool you use now.

On the other hand, if your PC has recently performed an update, or is in the process of updating Windows, you can expect high CPU use until it completes.

**N.B.** This question was asked on the day MS released [a slew of updates](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-december-2018-patch-tuesday-fixes-actively-used-zero-day-vulnerability/).

[image: Process Explorer]